# Get only file name from find command and mail

Tags: find, mailx

The following find command will results multiple files and send mail all those

```
find /home/cde -ctime -1 -name "Sum*pdf*" -exec uuencode {} {} \; |mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com
```

But I am getting attachments like `homecdeSum123.pdf` and `homecdeSum324.pdf`. How to get exact file names in my attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to have the attachments have filename like `Sum123.pdf` instead of `homecdeSum123.pdf`. I assume the latter name is produced by your mail program that removes the slashes in the path name when saving.

I think you should use a different way to call `uuencode`, removing the path name on the second parameter:

```
find /home/cde -ctime -1 -name "Sum*pdf*" | while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}" | mailx -s "subject" abc@example.com; done
```

This will send a separate mail for every file. The `${name##*/}` part will take the variable `$name`, remove everything up to and including the last slash and return the result.

If you want to send all files in one mail, just put the `mailx` part of the pipe to the end:

```
find /home/cde -ctime -1 -name "Sum*pdf*" | while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}"; done | mailx -s "subject" abc@example.com
```

Comment: @ Dubu Thanks alot. But I need to send all attachments in a single mail. Is it possible?

Comment: @user2910201 Yes, of course. I added this variant above.

Answer (score 2):

Try this oneliner

```
find /home/cde -ctime -1 -name "Sum*pdf*"  | uuencode files.txt | mailx -s "subject" abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: @ dchirikov Thank you, but it didn't work. I am getting files.txt as attachment and the names of files in the directory. I am not getting the actual attachments.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you need pdf attachments AND list of files?

Comment: @ dchirikov Yes I need pdf attachments alone no need of file list in mail.